# Removing Title in baposter class

Tags: errors, titles, posters, baposter

I am making a poster with the baposter.cls class. The class is a bit weird, and the title is inputed in the following:

```
{\sf\bf (Poster title)}
```

I would like to remove the title and have the boxes moved up to the top of the poster. However, whenever I comment out the above code, I get the following header message in my first box:

```
Argument of \headerbox has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.122 \headerbox
            {Some Notation}{name=notation,span=3,row=0,column=0}{
```

How would I go about removing the title and moving up the blocks?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[paperwidth=50cm,paperheight=100cm]{baposter}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{relsize} % Used for making text smaller in some places

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Border color of content boxes
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Background color for the content in the content boxes
\begin{document}

\background{ % Set the background to an image (background.pdf)
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west]
{\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{background}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{poster}{
grid=false,
borderColor=bordercol, % Border color of content boxes
headerColorOne=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=headercol2, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=headerfontcol, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=boxcolor, % Background color for the content in the content boxes
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers
headerfont=\Large\sf\bf, % Font modifiers for the text in the content box headers
textborder=rectangle,
background=user,
headerborder=open, % Change to closed for a line under the content box headers
boxshade=plain
}
{}
{\sf\bf Title of Poster}
\headerbox{Box title}
{name=title,span=3, row=0,column=0}{
Box body
}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

The code needs the class baposter.cls to run. I am not sure how to fix this also but it also needs a file called background.pdf (can be any pdf, just named background).

Comment: Could you provide the community with a more concrete example of what's going on; a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) is preferred. Ideally we want to copy-and-paste-and-compile the code you provide and see *exactly* what you're seeing (problem-wise). We can't do that at the moment. Please edit your post to do so.

Comment: I just edited the original post with a working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`baposter.cls` has a rather involved definition of the environment `poster`, wherein it sets some lengths `headerheight`, `colheight`, etc. If you leave the title argument blank and put `\setlength{\colheight}{\textheight}` after `\begin{poster}{...}` the headerboxes move to the top. Please try the code below.

```
\documentclass[paperwidth=50cm,paperheight=100cm]{baposter}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{relsize} % Used for making text smaller in some places
\usepackage{lipsum}

\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40} % Border color of content boxes
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80} % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0} % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255} % Background color for the content in the content boxes
\begin{document}

%\background{ % Set the background to an image (background.pdf)
%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%\draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west]
%{\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{background}};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}

%%% \begin{baposter}{settings}{Eye Catcher}{Title}{Author}{University Logo}
\begin{poster}{
grid=false,
borderColor=bordercol, % Border color of content boxes
headerColorOne=headercol1, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=headercol2, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=headerfontcol, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=boxcolor, % Background color for the content in the content boxes
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers
headerfont=\Large\sf\bf, % Font modifiers for the text in the content box headers
textborder=rectangle,
background=plain,
headerborder=open, % Change to closed for a line under the content box headers
boxshade=plain
}
{}
{}
{}
{}
%\headerbox{Box title}
%{name=title,span=3, row=0,column=0}{
%Box body
%}
\setlength{\colheight}{\textheight}%

\headerbox{Headerbox 1}{name=H1,column=0,row=0}{%
\lipsum[1]
}
\headerbox{Headerbox 2}{name=H2,column=1,row=0,span=2}{%
\lipsum[2-3]
}

\headerbox{Headerbox 3}{name=H3,column=1,span=2,below=H2,bottomaligned=H1}{%
\lipsum[4]
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```